# why are .pc files not listed in one place

Tags: debian, libraries, pkg-config

I am on Debian buster. I was reading the manpage of pkg-config and found that .pc files are and can be listed in many places . From the manpage -

> pkg-config  retrieves  information  about  packages from special
>   metadata files. These files are named after the package, and has a .pc
>   extension.  On most systems, pkg-config looks in /usr/lib/pkgconfig,
>   /usr/share/pkgconfig, /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig and
>   /usr/local/share/pkgconfig for these files.  It will additionally look
>   in the colon-separated (on Windows, semicolon-separated) list of
>   directories specified by the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.

- From pkg-config manpage

sure enough I saw that there are packages in /usr/lib/pkgconfig/, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ and /usr/share/pkgconfig/ , while I can understand the /usr/local/.. part for locally compiled/built apps. I do not understand why there is a distinction between /usr/lib/pkgconfig/ and /usr/share/pkgconfig . Is it something to do with some things need to be in userspace https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space or something else entirely ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction is related to [architecture independence](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s11.html). `.pc` files which might be architecture-specific go in `/usr/lib` (on Debian, `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` for pre-multiarch packages, `/usr/lib/<triplet>/pkgconfig` for multiarch packages), `.pc` files which *are sure to be* architecture-independent can go in `/usr/share` (only `/usr/share/pkgconfig`, no need to distinguish triplets here).